# spock trying to use wrong groovy version

Tags: maven, groovy, spock

This is my new pom, simplified, I created new project and added just minimum to be able to run spock

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxxx</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>scenarios</name>
<description>desc</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>


<parent>
    <groupId>yyyr</groupId>
    <artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

but still I cannot run test, now I get

Information:Groovyc: While compiling tests of model:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/ast/MethodCallTransformation needed for org.codehaus.groovy.macro.transform.MacroTransformation
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.JointCompilationClassLoader._defineClass(JointCompilationClassLoader.java:41)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:376)
....

Comment: Can you post your full pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, the POM is important. Your import of a 2.4 Groovy version must come from another dependency or maybe even from your own parent POM or BoM. I can only speculate. The exclusions for Spock should not be necessary, even though that Spock version by default uses Groovy 2.5.4 and not 2.5.7.

Answer (score 0):

The above POM (the one I edited in the question) worked, in include spock and all dependencies